# How to make ajax call for creating drop drown of states in joomla 2.5

Tags: ajax, joomla

I am a beginner in joomla .I have a contact form in the front end where i want to get the dropdown of states when a country is selected.This contact form display is at myproject/components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default_form.php . I have a country drop down there . I want to make an ajax call to the function filterState() in the controller of contacts . this is my ajax code

```
`<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $( "#jform_contact_country" ).change(function(){
          var id = $( "#jform_contact_country option:selected" ).val();
          alert(id); 
          $.ajax({
              url: "index.php",
              data: 'option=com_contact&task=filterState()&country_id='+id,
              success: function(data) {
                    alert('succes');
                }
              }); 
        });
    });
</script>`
```

method filterStae is inside the contact.php which is inside myproject/components/com_contact/controllers/ . But when i change the country this function is not called and call goes to index.php and is not going to this page ? how to actually invoke this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change code to this one:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jform_contact_country").change(function(){
      var id = $("#jform_contact_country option:selected").val();
      alert(id); 
      $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_contact&task=CONTROLLER_NAME.filterState&country_id="+id,
        success: function(data) {
          alert('succes');
        }
      }); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

Change **CONTROLLER_NAME** with your controller filename in /controllers/
As you can see from my code, to access controller's method, **task** value should be `CONTROLLER_NAME.METHOD_NAME`

Comment: By the way, you can always try if URL is working properly by copying it into your browser address bar ;)

Comment: Thanks dude ....it worked , now have to retrieve the states from db , i may need ur help again , so keep in touch buddy ....thanks again

Comment: Any time mate :) If my answer helped you, it would be nice if you could mark it as accepted and vote up for it :)

Comment: pal , can we use $model = $this->getModel('states'); inside filterstate function to load the model , where states.php is where i defined the function to get the states . that function is defined inside a class in states.php . does joomla 2.5 allow getModel , i am not getting a proper documentation from net ..... some site saying its deprecated from 1.6

Comment: Try $model = $this->getModel('MODEL_NAME','ENTITY_NAMEModel'); and then $model->METHOD_NAME(); Where (you can get your model name and entity name from model class name, its made Entity_NameModelModel_Name) so lets say if your model class is called ContactsModelStates, and method is called getStates(), your code would be $model = $this->getModel('States', 'ContactsModel'); $model->getStates();